# Login google não funciona após publicar na Play Store

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-plus

Meu código está todo certo. Quando eu uso o aplicativo a partir de um emulador, ou gerando APK e instalando nos dispositivos o login com a conta google é efetuado perfeitamente. O problema surgiu quando eu fui publicar na playstore, de repente o meu login com google parou de funcionar. Quando clico para efetuar o login, aparece a mensagem do google para escolher uma conta, eu escolho uma e nada acontece. 
É a segunda vez que isso acontece. Quando publico na playstore deixa de funcionar. O que posso fazer? O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Bota uma imagem desse login que você está fazendo.

Comment: Adicione o código da sua autenticação, pra entendermos como ela é feita e possivelmente te ajudar.

Comment: Como você gerou a api key? Usou SHA-1 com a chave?

Comment: O problema é que quando você publica na playstore, você tem que assinar o apk, o que muda a chave gerada do login do google. Tentou gerar a chave de api de login, com o sha-1 do seu keystore que assinou o apk?